# How to pass Data to Flask_Admin's View's HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-admin

I'm currently trying to populate widgets on the Flask_Admin Home Page with data from my Database.
However, I'm having trouble passing the data into the HTML. Here is my view, where I want to render `accountBalance`:

```
class MyView(BaseView):
    accountBalance = 0

    @expose('/')
    def index(self, accountBalance, **kwargs):
        self.accountBalance = accountBalance
        return self.render('admin/index.html', accountBalance=accountBalance)

# And app code:
accountBalance = 10000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    admin = Admin(app, name='MyAdmin', template_mode='bootstrap3')
    admin.add_view(views.MyView(accountBalance))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And here's the HTML/Jinja logic in admin/index.html, which tries to render the `accountBalance` I passed in above:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}

{% block head_css %}
{{ super() }}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='sb-admin-2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock head_css %}

{% block body %}
{{ super() }}
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">This is your balance:</div>
                                    <div> {% accountBalance %}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

I've been following examples to try to get this to work, where the '{% accountBalance %}' in the HTML should be the value of `accountBalance` I'm trying to pass in, but to no prevail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ accountBalance }}`. `{% .. %}` is used for statements like for loop and if conditions.

From the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/):

> `{% ... %}` for Statements
>
> `{{ ... }}` for Expressions to print to the template output

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the Jinja part, but I'm still having trouble setting value of 'accountBalance'. Am I passing it in correctly in `index()`?

Comment: @TDiddy Having no experience with Flask-Admin, I can't say for sure. But, I believe you can't pass it like this. `views.MyView(accountBalance)` is passing it like a constructor argument. So, you should declare a constructor `def __init__(self, accountBalance)` and set the value of `self.accountBalance` in it. Please test it and let me know the results as well :)

Comment: OP: Did you get this to work?